# Why am I getting a deprecated warning in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-warnings, deprecated

I am getting a warning about setText method when I am not even using it.  Why does XCode display this warning message?

[alt text http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/deprecated.jpg](http://www.angryhacker.com/toys/deprecated.jpg)

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, we'll never be able to tell you.

Comment: Jeff, are you browsing without images again?  1995 called.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `cell.text` property is deprecated in iPhone OS 3.0 and greater, because new table cell types allow multiple labels. Instead, use `cell.textLabel.text` to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

this is how properties work

`x = object.field` is (by default) the same as calling `x = [object field]`

and `object.field = x` is (by default) the same as calling `[object setField:x]`

Answer (score 2):

The up two answers are more than correct. Just to add some references from Apple's Dev. Believe that will solve all of your questions. Please take a look at the session for "[Object Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html)"

Answer (score 1):

By setting a class's field the way you are, you are actually calling the setText method